# Hybris - PromotionSourceRule - rule condition qualifying categories is always falling back to other catalog

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

> Issue: Only in Test environment but the same working fine in local.

I have two catalogs

*CA - Staged and Online*

*US - Staged and Online*

Backoffice, When I try to set create promotion rule conditions I pick qualifying categories and try to add "Hardware" category from US:Online catalog but its always falling back to CA:Staged after save and reopen.

[image]

Whatever the catalog version's category I select it always falls back to CA:Staged.

Note: Category "Hardware" is present in both CA and US catalog
This is happening in our Test environment and not in local

I worried if this relation might have impact but my trial and error steps didn't help reproduce the issue in local.

```
INSERT_UPDATE CatalogVersionToRuleEngineContextMapping;context(name)[unique=true];catalogVersion(catalog(id),version)[unique=true]
```

### Rule parameter

I checked the rule parameter it doesn't persist the catalogversion for the category

```
{
  "uuid": "b0b0f50c-3fde-437b-a579-afcfd5ba10ea",
  "type": "List(ItemType(Category))",
  "value": [
    "Hardware"
  ]
},
```

where the category's catalog version is persisted so that on fetching back the rule it is loaded back with catalog version?

I expect the selected catalog version of category should never change. Is there any configuration that it always falls back to default catalog?

Comment: Is the promotion created for US website or for Canada Website (Promotion has a "Website" attribute ) ?

Comment: Its for US site. Yep I have a right website filled in. Do you think on rendering the catalogversion if pulled out based on the website chosen?

Comment: yes, that was my assumption

Comment: Yep the website attribute is also fine